# Mixing percona and mariadb in a galera cluster

Tags: mariadb, percona, galera

Assuming both percona and mariadb runs the same engine (innoDB), can i use them interchangeably in a galera cluster? If it is possible, is there anything I should know before doing it?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing so?

Comment: evaluate to see which is better

Comment: So set up a dev cluster of each and test it. Running a mix of the two in *production* as an experiment to see which one you like is crazy.

Comment: not deploying it in production, i am currently trying to evaluate to see which is a better choice

Comment: Then do the proper thing and build a dev cluster for each and see which one works better for your use case.